# comparing and finding error between two arrays of different sizes using numpy

Tags: python, arrays, python-2.7, numpy, vectorization

I have csv files that all vary in length. However, I have a truth file that has samples at 10x per second, but the data that is being recorded is recorded once per second on second boundaries. I am trying to match these second boundaries to compare the error for automating tests. Below are an example of what my csv files look like.

Truth File

```
0,   1
0.1, 2
0.2, 3
.
.
.
x, n
```

Measured File

```
0, 1.01
1, 9.99
3, 30.05
.
.
.
x, n
```

I pull in the dataset for the truth file on each data-pull for my measured results, and I am trying to do a quick comparison to see if the time value associated with data value in the measured file is within a margin of error between the same time value in the truth file. How exactly can I search through an array for whether one of the values is equivalent without having to use a for loop to search through the array everytime I sample for data changes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update:

Assumptions:

- data and truth are given in four arrays `tr_t` (truth times) `tr_v` (truth values) `da_t` (data times) and `da_v` (data values)
- the truth data are complete and sampled at 10 Hz, in other words `tr_t = np.arange(N) / 10`

Under these assumptions the index of the truth record matching a given data sample `(da_t[i], da_v[i])` is `ind = int(np.round(da_t[i] * 10))` if data times can't be relied upon to fall exactly on tenths of seconds `np.isclose(da_t[i], tr_t[ind], reltol, abstol)` can be used to filter out insufficient matches. Values are compared in the same manner.

In vectorised form:

```
inds = np.round(10 * da_t).astype(int)
mask = np.isclose(da_v, tr_v[inds], reltol, abstol) \  # required
       & np.isclose(da_t, tr_t[inds], reltol, abstol)  # optional
```

Finding the indices if `tr_t` is irregular but still in ascending order:

```
inds = np.searchsorted(tr_t, da_t)
inds += tr_t[(inds + 1) % len(tr_t)] - da_t > da_t - tr_t[inds]
```

Comment: The example data suggests that the measured points are not present for every integer second, so a non-trivial `data_timestamps` is needed.

Comment: @AndrasDeak It suffices for the truth times to be complete. These are represented in a way that suggests they are. The `truth_data[data_timestamps]` then picks the correct reference values to match against the data. Simple example: decimated truth times 0,1,2,3,... data timestamps 0,1,3 then decimated truth data at positions 0,1,3 will be selected, which is correct. Note that the Q clearly states that the data times are full seconds. And finally, I do mention admittedly very superficially, how to address the case of truth times not being regular and complete.

Comment: @PaulPanzer This would be good with the exception that I have another dataset that I will be comparing that will also be recorded 10 times per second meaning I can't just discard those truth values. I am looking for a way to compare a position in my measured data file against the corresponding truth value at the same time. My other data file is recorded at this faster rate and cannot simply be compared using an increment because it skips around in time due to software imperfections.

Comment: @nichollsg As long as your truth file doesn't skip any times and if your data times are in clean tenths of seconds it still works. just multiply the timestamps by 10, round, convert to int and use them as indices into the full truth array.

Answer (score 2):

If your truth file and measured file contain time points that are close enough, you can pair your data using these time points:

```
import numpy as np

# set up dummy data
truthdat = np.arange(25)[:,None]*[0.1,1]
measdat = np.array([[0.01, 0.01], [0.99, 9.99], [2.01,20.05]])

# find the temporal indices which correspond to one another
i_meas,i_truth = np.where(np.isclose(measdat[:,None,0],truthdat[:,0],atol=0.05))
```

What we did was make use of array broadcasting, allowing us to compare each time in `measdat` with each time in `truthdat` in a vectorized way. Also note that I allowed for a bit of variation in time data as well. In case these are exactly the same, you could just use `measdat[:,None,0]==truthdat[:,0]` inside `np.where` instead.

The resulting indices give us the paired data points:

```
>>> measdat[i_meas]
array([[  1.00000000e-02,   1.00000000e-02],
       [  9.90000000e-01,   9.99000000e+00],
       [  2.01000000e+00,   2.00500000e+01]])

>>> truthdat[i_truth]
array([[  0.,   0.],
       [  1.,  10.],
       [  2.,  20.]])
```

Now you can similarly use `np.isclose` with a tolerance of your choice to compare the second column of these data pairs:

```
# tell if all values are within atol=0.05 absolute error
are_close = np.allclose(measdat[i_meas,1],truthdat[i_truth,1],atol=0.05)

# compute the error for each measured point
abserrors = measdat[i_meas,1] - truthdat[i_truth,1]
```

and carry on with any other post-processing as you need.